# Call ruby class method and parameters stored in proc

Tags: ruby, proc

I have a `proc` thats setup as follows:

```
@method_to_call = Proc.new { || {:method=>'some_method',:user_id=>1 } }
```

And now I want to call the method `some_method` with the parameter `user_id`

```
def some_method(user_id)
 # does something
end
```

The catch is the proc can also have different parameters such as:

```
@method_to_call = Proc.new { || {:method=>'some_method_two',:user_id=>1, :app_id=>2 } }
```

Which would call:

```
def some_method_two(user_id,app_id)
  # do something
end
```

I currently have a method as shown:

```
def handle_action
  parts = @method_to_call.call
  curr_method = parts[:method]
  if curr_method == "some_method"
     some_method parts[:user_id]
  elsif curr_method == "some_method_two"
     some_method_two parts[:user_id], parts[:app_id]
  end
end
```

but i want something like...

```
def handle_action
   # call method in proc and pass parameters stored in proc dynamically
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you structured the procs as a method name and an argument list:

```
Proc.new { ['some_method', [1]] }
Proc.new { ['some_method_two', [1, 2]] }
```

You could then do

```
def handle_action
  method, args = @method_to_call.call

  public_send(method, *args)
end
```

If this harms understanding (given that `user_id` and `app_id` are no longer documented), you could always convert those methods to use keyword arguments, and then rewrite as

```
def some_method_two(user_id:, app_id:)
  do_something
end

@method_to_call = Proc.new { ['some_method_two', { user_id: 1, app_id: 2 }] }

def handle_action
  method, args = @method_to_call.call

  public_send(method, **args)
end
```

Out of interest, is there any reason you need to use procs in the first place? Is there a requirement to delay evaluation of the method arguments?

Comment: It's just convenient for us to use a closure with the specs provided.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer already shows what's possible. I just want to share that you can call methods inside from Proc as well.

```rb
@method_to_call = Proc.new do |**kwargs|
  some_method(kwargs.except(:method)) if kwargs[:method] == 'some_method'
  some_method_2(kwargs.except(:method)) if kwargs[:method] == 'some_method_2'
end

def some_method(user_id:)
  puts "User ID: #{user_id}"
end

def some_method_2(user_id:, app_id:)
  puts "User ID: #{user_id}, App ID: #{app_id}"
end

@method_to_call.call({ method: 'some_method', user_id: 1 })
@method_to_call.call({ method: 'some_method_2', user_id: 1, app_id: 2 })
```

Output:

```
User ID: 1
User ID: 1, App ID: 2
```

Note that:
[`Hash#except`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) method is available in Rails and recently Ruby also supports this from [Ruby 3.00](https://rubyapi.org/3.0/o/hash#method-i-except)